# How to set unique name to ngModelGroup in the form on different places

Tags: angular, forms, nested, ngmodel

I have a Component, the selector is: app-common-component.

The app-common-component based on an ngModelGroup :

```
<fieldset ngModelGroup>
</fieldset>
```

I have a form, which separated to two components app-component-a and app-component-b

```
<form>
  <app-component-a></app-component-a>
  <app-component-b></app-component-b>
</form>
```

The app-component-a contains the app-common-component

```
<fieldset ngModelGroup="componenta">
  <app-common-component></app-common-component>
</fieldset>
```

The app-component-b contains the app-common-component also

```
<fieldset ngModelGroup="componentb">
  <app-common-component></app-common-component>
</fieldset>
```

My question is how can I set the ngModelGroup name of the app-common-component in different places?

I would like to see below the form the following:

```
mainForm
  controls
    componenta
      controls
        unique name of the app-common-component
    componentb
      controls
        unique name of the app-common-component
```

Comment: just pass it as `@Input()`. Or did I understand the problem wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Andrei you can use Input property to set unique name or you can set global varibale inside common component. Then increment it by 1 for every newinstance something like this.

**common.component.ts**

```
let uniqueId = 0;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-common-component',
  template: `
   <fieldset [ngModelGroup]="groupName">
   </fieldset>
  `,
})
export class AppCommonComponent  {
  groupName = uniqueId++; 

}
```

Comment: Hi,
The name part with uniqueID works well. but hierarchically I not see one of the app-common -component below the form when I debugging it. 
Insteadof the mentioned hierarchy I see the app-common -component on the same level where the appücomponentüa and appücomponentüb exists

Comment: I found why at the viewProvider Instead of NgForm I should use NgModelGroup.